# matplotlib interactive plots don't draw

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cygwin

I'm trying to use interactive mode in matplotlib, but the graph isn't drawn.  It works in the python shell, but not when run in a script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

plt.ion()
plt.plot([1, 4, 2])
print('sleeping')
time.sleep(2)
print('updating')
plt.plot([1, 3, 2, 4])
time.sleep(10)
```

In the python shell, it draws the graph and two seconds later, adds another line.  But if run using "python3 test.py", only a black frame appears.

I'm running under Cygwin, using python3.6m and Cygwin64 terminal (mintty).  I just installed Cygwin, so everything is relatively up-to-date.

Comment: But after 12 seconds you see the complete graph or not? Of course using `time.sleep` is a bit dangerous with GUIs because they usually need to stay responsive and never "sleep". So I would replace `time.sleep(n)` with `plt.pause(n)`.

Comment: After 12 seconds the application exits and the frame disappears.  Yes, I know about time.sleep() but thanks for pointing it out.  I also realize a different approach is matplotlib animation, but a trivial example of that also didn't work.  plt.pause() causes interactive mode to stop happening.  After the return from pause, everything behaves as though ion() was never called, and calling it again has no apparent effect.

Comment: Actually, regarding `sleep`: I had hoped that interactive mode would avoid this issue (hoping the GUI started a thread.)  I see now that `sleep` pauses the  GUI.  So I'm not at all sure what the benefit of interactive mode is, and I think I need two threads.  Of course that raises a host of other issues.

Comment: To keep the window open you would need a blocking `plt.show()`. So at the end add `plt.ioff(); plt.show()`. Not sure if this also solves the issue of the black frames.

Comment: Interactive mode does not start a new thread. It just emulates the usual GUI event loop inside the main thread.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use interactive mode is to avoid blocking.  Regardless, why is the behavior different (correct, as expected) when running under the python shell but not when running as a script?

Comment: In the shell, python stays open and there is no reason the window should close, while when run as script python terminates and hence the window closes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196824/discussion-between-jeff-learman-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem before.
The solution for this problem is:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks, but that causes `_backend_tk.py` error `from . import _tkagg RuntimeError: No such process`

Comment: Which backend are you using instead? (`plt.get_backend()`)

Comment: Qt5Agg is the backend